# Wordpress. Запустить функцию из файла function.php в файле своего кастомного плагина

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Здравстуйте. Пишу свой маленький плагин для вордпрес.

И есть у меня функция(фильтр), которуя я вызываю в файле function.php и вона исправно работает. (прячет выбранный метод оплаты, если в корзине есть товар из некоторой категории)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','filter_gateways');
function filter_gateways($gateways){
$payment_NAME = 'paypal'; // <-- some payment method
$category_ID_1 = '6'; // <-- some category of products
global $woocommerce;
foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if($term->term_id == $category_ID_1){
            unset($gateways[$payment_NAME]);
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
return $gateways;}
```

Дальше вопрос - как мне использовать этот фильтр в плагине своем? Ибо я хочу передать некоторые значеня из базы туда.
Если просто размещаю в своем файле с функциями, то ничего не работает.

Прошу совета, и не сварить за незнание, я только начинающий.

Comment: уточню - эта функция работает в файле `functions.php`в папке темы
а я хочу запускать у себя в папке плагина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все просто - надо поместить этот код целиком в конец основного файла вашего плагина. В тот файл, где в заголовке написано

```
`/*
 Plugin Name: .......
.........
*/`
```